# Setting Gnome registry (GConf) mandatory settings automatically

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, gnome, gconf

*TL;DR: Have found some possibilities, but documentation leaves too many questions unanswered for me to deploy them with confidence.*

I'd like to roll out some mandatory GConf settings across the user workstations on our network.  After some investigation there appear to be several options for changing mandatory settings, but each leaves me with questions about how to apply it correctly.

**`gconf-editor`**

- **Method**: From the GUI, run `gksudo gconf-editor` and select File > New Mandatory Window.
- **Pros**:

  - Definitely works: this is what I've used on smaller installation in the past.
- **Cons**:

  - Not automated, so not really an option.
  - Scales poorly with large numbers of settings.

**`gconftool-2`**

- **Method**: Call `gconftool-2` with the '`--config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory`' option.
- **Pros**:

  - Can be automated.
- **Cons**:

  - Apparently conflicting directions on use of `--direct` flag.
  - (minor) Requires separate command for each individual setting.

**`/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory/`**

- **Method**: Alter/create files under `/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory/` directly.
- **Pros**:

  - Fits well with our existing file distribution infrastructure.
  - Scales well to large numbers of settings.
- **Cons**:

  - Appears not to be an officially supported method.
  - Unclear how to avoid upsetting `gconfd`.
  - Wrapper script to stop/restart `gconfd` might cause user issues.

The GNOME documentation gives [some examples](http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/gconf-8.html.en) for `gconftool-2` which all use the `--direct` flag.  However, the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gconftool-2.1.html) says that the `--direct` flag 'Requires that gconfd is not running.'  Is that not relevant for this scenario (I'd be running as root, not a logged in user), or would I need to detect whether a `gconfd` is running and pass/not pass that flag accordingly?

I'd ideally like to sync the files in `/etc/` directly, but I can't find any indication of how the daemons might respond to this (e.g. whether they might pick up inconsistent settings, or need to be restarted).  Sandwiching the file updates between commands to stop/restart `gconfd` should avoid problems with the daemon itself, but I imagine could play havoc with an active user session.

Can anyone with more experience of GConf clarify any of these matters, or provide details of methods that they're using?  We're running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, but I'd be happy to hear of solutions running on any platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your requirements, I'd go with adding settings to `/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory` (I presume you're using puppet, chef, or something similar). You will need to log the user out and stop gconfd (`gconftool-2 --shutdown`; it usually remains running for a few minutes after logout) to have settings changes take effect.

Comment: Thanks; and yes, we are using Puppet.  Just to clarify your point about shutting down `gconfd`: are you saying that changes shouldn't be made until the user has logged out and `gconfd` has been shut down; or that files can be added to `/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory` at _any_ time, but they won't have any impact until `gconfd` is restarted?  (I don't mind waiting until the user next logs out/in before settings go live, but they probably won't want Puppet to forcibly log them out. ;)

Comment: You can push the settings changes whenever you want, they just won't apply until the user logs out and gconfd is stopped.